# Blurry Library - How to blur a single view?

Tags: android

I can't get this library to work. Documentation is not helping either

https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

On the github:

// from View

`Blurry.with(context).capture(view).into(imageView)`

what is the `.capture(view)`? is that the viewgroup its in?

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .load("https://i.imgur.com/8kTahFy.jpg")
                .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        Blurry.with(BuisnessActivity.this).capture(mConstraintLayout).into(mProfilePicture);

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(mProfilePicture);
```

doesn't do anything to the picture I want to blur.

Comment: returning true in onResourceReady should apply the blur but it may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it on two emulators:

`Nexus 5 API 27`

`Pixel 2 API 29`

and the blur does not work on either of them. However once I use my real device with `API 30`... it works.